# Cytoscape Passthrough mapping

Tags: cytoscape

I have a question regarding passthrough mapping on Cytoscape.
Let us say I have my nodes that belong to discreet groups. Those groups appear on a different column that I call Cat. How can I make the node fill colour to be according to Cat? I know I can do it with discrete mapping, choosing the Cat colours individually, but what if I have loads of Cats? When I choose Passthrough mappping, which I do not know how it works, nothing happens.
Thanks for your help.
Best,
David R.

Answer (score 0):

Passthrough mapping does sort of what it sounds like -- it maps the value in the column cell to the visual attribute.  In this case, you are mapping whatever is in Cats to a Color.  Now, if you have a value of "Group 1", and Cytoscape maps it to a color, you wind up with ... nothing since Cytoscape doesn't know how to do that mapping.  My suggestion would be to use discrete mapping, but let Cytoscape choose the colors.  If you right-click on the "Discrete Mapping" and then go to "Mapping Value Generators" you'll see a number of options for automatically assigning colors.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks a lot Scooter, that is exactly what I was looking for. My right click was missing there. Best, David R.